# Prove or Disprove $A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq D $ is equivalent to $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Can this statement be proved? because if i insert values, LHS is not equal to RHS.
For example,
let  $A=\{1\}, B=\{1,2\}, C=\{1\}, D=\{1\}$ then
$A\times B = \{1,2\}, C\times D=\{1\}$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a Mathjax tutorial.  The [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) $A\times B=\{(a,b)\mid a\in A, b\in B\},$ so $\{1\}\times\{1,2\}=\{(1,1),(1,2)\}$

Comment: Nice name. ${}{}$

Comment: Please check for a possible typo. Maybe the condition is $A\subseteq C\land B\subseteq D$, i.e. $\land$ ( "and") instead of $\cap$ (" intersection ").

Comment: @StinkingBishop The original unedited post shows that is what he meant.

Comment: $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$ doesn't not imply that $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$. For instance, $\varnothing \times \{1,\dots,100\} = \varnothing \subseteq \{0\} \times \{1\}$ but $\{1,\dots,100\} \nsubseteq \{1\}$.

Comment: @azif00 Indeed, one needs to require that $A$ and $B$ be nonempty for the statement to be true.

Answer (score 1):

The Cartesian product makes a set of pairs.  So for example:

$$\{1, 2\} \times \{a, b, c\} = \{(1, a), (1, b), (1, c), (2, a), (2, b), (2, c)\}$$

It is all possible pairs where the first element is from the first set and the second element is from the second set.  Try working out some examples with this Cartesian product definition.

Answer (score 1):

We only have $\Rightarrow$.

To prove $\Rightarrow:$ If $A\times B=\emptyset$, we are done. Suppose
that $A\times B\neq\emptyset$. Let $(x,y)\in A\times B$, then $x\in A$
and $y\in B$. $x\in A$ and $A\subseteq C$ implies that $x\in C$.
$y\in B$ and $B\subseteq D$ implies that $y\in D$. Therefore $(x,y)\in C\times D$.
This shows that $A\times B\subseteq C\times D$.

We do not have $\Leftarrow$.

Counter-example. Let $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\emptyset$, $C=\{1\}$, $D=\{3\}$.
Since $B=\emptyset$, we have that $A\times B=\emptyset$. It follows
that $A\times B\subseteq C\times D$. On the other hand, clearly $A\not\subseteq C$.